# How to combine Inner Join and Left Join in SQL Query statement?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Given this Diagram:

[image]

What is the right way to use join that will includes all necessary fields from different tables (person name, employee number, status of contracts, job name, department name, pcn/item name, country, and religion)? BUT I want also to include all persons that choose not to put either thier country or religion. I have this query:

```
SELECT persons.fullname, religions.religion_name, countries.country_name
FROM countries INNER JOIN (religions INNER JOIN (persons INNER JOIN 
((jobs INNER JOIN (departments INNER JOIN pcns ON departments.ID = pcns.department_id) ON jobs.ID = pcns.job_id) 
INNER JOIN (employees INNER JOIN contracts ON employees.ID = contracts.employee_id) ON pcns.ID = contracts.pcn_id) 
ON persons.ID = employees.person_id) ON religions.ID = persons.religion) ON countries.ID = persons.country_id;
```

I used `LEFT JOIN` but I got an error. Right now, I only query all my tables except for `countries` and `religions` then I made a function that whenever a user clicks particular person this function will return its religion and/or country. I am just curious how to achieve it in a **SELECT query**.

Comment: The correct syntax to join mulitple tables is not like this. You should check the doc. Also even with the valid syntax I am pretty sure you will be suffered from double counted value if you ar going to select with aggregate function as you are joining mulitple to many tables.

Comment: It looks like correct Access SQL syntax. @tom10271

Comment: Please show the query with LEFT JOIN that you tried, and the error message. @AnirudhLou